# Is it possible to make branches with Linq "in" where clause as I do in MSSQL?

Tags: c#

I would like to write the same or almost the same query in c# as I have written in MSSQL. The Query can be switched between above average or all data mode.

In C# from this state of the query my knowledge is poor. I would like to make something like in SQL way.

```
public static List<AllOrderData> AllOrderDataList(bool checkedActive)
{
List<AllOrderData> returnList = new List<AllOrderData>();

int IntToMakeBranches = checkedActive ? 1 : 2;

return returnList = (from a in OrderedProductList
          join b in ProductList on a.ProductID equals b.ProductID
          join c in ProductCategoryList on b.ProductCategoryID equals c.ProductCategoryID
          join d in CustomerOrderList on a.CustomerOrderID equals d.CustomerOrderID
           join e in CustomerList on d.CustomerID equals e.CustomerID
           select (new AllOrderData(
                     b.ProductName,
                     c.ProductCategoryName,
                     d.OrderDateTime,                                                    
                     e.CustomerName.Substring(0, e.CustomerName.IndexOf(' '))         
                     e.CustomerName.Substring(e.CustomerName.IndexOf(' '),
                     e.CustomerName.Length - e.CustomerName.IndexOf(' ')),
                     a.OrderedAmount,
                     a.OrderedAmount * b.ProductListprice,
                     PriceCategory(a.OrderedAmount * b.ProductListprice)))).ToList();
}
```

This is the SQL way, working fine. When parameter is 2 all data turn up,
When parameter is 1 only data above average turn up.

```
SELECT a.ProductName
       ,b.ProductCategoryName
       ,c.OrderDateTime
       ,SUBSTRING(d.CustomerName, 1,CHARINDEX(' ',d.CustomerName)) AS 'FirstName'
       ,SUBSTRING(d.CustomerName, CHARINDEX(' ',d.CustomerName), LEN(d.CustomerName) - CHARINDEX(' ',d.CustomerName) +1) AS 'LastName'
       ,e.OrderedAmount
       ,(e.OrderedAmount * a.ProductListPrice) AS 'Order value'
       ,CASE
       WHEN e.OrderedAmount*a.ProductListPrice <= 1000 THEN 'Low'
       WHEN e.OrderedAmount*a.ProductListPrice > 1000 AND (e.OrderedAmount*a.ProductListPrice) < 2000 THEN 'Middle'
       ELSE 'High'
       END AS 'Price category'
FROM OrderedProduct e
JOIN Product a ON a.ProductID = e.ProductID
JOIN ProductCategory b ON b.ProductCategoryID = a.ProductCategoryID
JOIN CustomerOrder c ON c.CustomerOrderID = e.CustomerOrderID
JOIN Customer d ON d.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE {0} > (CASE
WHEN (SELECT AVG(OrderedAmount*UnitPrice) FROM OrderedProduct) < (e.OrderedAmount*e.UnitPrice) THEN 0
ELSE 1
END)
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting a similar [linq where clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-clause). You should be able to perform the Average query first & pass that as a parameter too.

Comment: I have a lot of solutions in my mind. For Exaple in MSSQL I have used T-SQL to get the data but my teacher told me that the data can be taken by only a query without declarations so I should try to find it out. I could do it with a WHERE/CASE clause. I thought that there is a similar way in C#. So probably it is not possible to make a branching after a Where clause like in MSSQL.

Comment: With you provided code we cannot reproduce anything. Have you tried something like returnList.Where(m => !checkedActive || (checkedActive && [your-average-condition])).ToList()

Comment: Finally I used your method:  where !checkedActive || checkedActive && (a.OrderedAmount*a.UnitPrice) > OrderedProductList.Average(x=> x.OrderedAmount*x.UnitPrice). Thanks for help!

Comment: @Brokkoli: note that you don't need to add checkedActive in the second half of the OR clause :  !checkedActive || (a.OrderedAmounta.UnitPrice) > OrderedProductList.Average(x=> x.OrderedAmountx.UnitPrice)

Comment: As a novice I always  type the two ways in, slowly I should get rid of this bed habit. Thank you for your sharp-sightedness!